# What is the best way to generate unique session IDs?

Tags: session, sessionid

I want to generate a 16 character alphanumeric Session ID string. What is the best way to do this so that it is guaranteed that the string generated will be unique every time?

Note: I will be using C++ to generate the session IDs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Typically you would create a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier) using whatever language/OS services provide such a service. Commonly available GUIDs are 16 *bytes* long, which in hex representation would be 32 characters. You can [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encode that and get it slightly smaller (22 characters or so). Do you really need exactly 16 *characters*?

Comment: How do I create a GUID in C++ for UNIX? Are there APIs available in C++?

Comment: On Linux and some other platforms, you can use `libuuid`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid Or, you can use the `uuidgen` shell command.

Comment: I read in a few different places (including SO) that GUIDs are predictable. Does this introduce a security risk when using as a session ID?

Comment: @aggregate1166877: There's nothing inherently predictable about a GUID, it all depends on how you generate it. Some common OS services generate them based on a network adapter MAC address and a timestamp; those are predictable. If you generate them with an actual random number generator, then they're not predictable.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GUID. How you generate one will depend on the platform you're running on.